# Can a parent class have methods referencing fields of child classes?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

Writing out the question it seems like the answer should be no, but hear me out:

I'm trying to make a simple "Spellcasting" system in Unity (C#). I'm having some trouble figuring out the correct data/inherritance structure. I have a "Spell" class, and (for now) two child classes, "Fireball" and "Lightning".

```
Class Fireball : Spell 
{ 
  public float dmg;
  public float projectileSpeed;
}

Class Lightning : Spell 
{
  public float dmg;
  public float stunDuration;
}
```

When a spell is cast, it takes in a Caster object, which contains potential modifiers to the fields of the cast spell.

```
Class Caster 
{
  public float dmgModifier;
  public float projectileSpeedModifier;
  public float stunDurationModifier;
}
```

Now what I would want, is to have a method in the Spell class, which applies the appropriate modifications to the fields in a spell object. This should be called right after a spell object is instantiated.

```
Class Spell 
{
  public void UpdateStats(Caster caster) 
  {
    dmg *= caster.dmgModifier;
    projectileSpeed *= caster.projectileSpeedModifier; //Only apply if it has this field
    stunDuration *= caster.stunDurationModifier //Only apply if it has this field
  }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Spell has no reference to these fields in the subclasses. But is there a way to say "If the Spell object has a field "projectileSpeed", then you should apply the appropriate modification using "caster.projectileSpeed".

Is something like this possible? If it is possible, is it just "a hack"? (I'm trying to learn how to do things the "correct" way, so would like a somewhat "natural" way to do it). Should I reconsider my inherritance structure or is there some other way to achieve a similar functionality?

As I'm doing it now, I have a separate "UpdateStats" method for each subclass containing only the correct modifications. The problem is that then when creating new spells, I always have to check which stats it has, and which modifications it should use, and write a new (Very similar) method for each child class. It seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Another thing I have tried is having a separate "SpellStats" class, which every spell gets an instance of:

```
Class SpellStats 
{
  public float dmg;
  public float projectileSpeed;
  public float stunDuration;
}
```

Using this approach I can correctly update all the stats with one method, but the problem then is that a lot of the information in the object is unused; a fireball spell never need to use its "spellStats.stunDuration". Thus this also seems incorrect. Is there a way to have something like this, but being able to specify in the Fireball class which fields of the SpellStats class it actually needs to see?

Comment: Yep, virtual/abstract methods were designed with that purpose - having defined in a base class, they can be overriden in derived types for their own needs.

Comment: ^ beat me by a few seconds.  You could use a virtual method and override it in each child class.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual

Comment: You could create an `interface ProjectileSpell {float Speed {get; set;}}` , have `Fireball` and other applicable types implement it, and then use patterns.

Comment: @Ryan But that still requires a "different" implementation for each child class, right? The problem I'm having is that all these "different" implementations are basically doing the same thing, just with different fields. I was wondering if maybe there was a way to generalize this method, and not having to rewrite it for every new subclass?

Comment: @AluanHaddad What do you mean by "and then use patterns"?

Comment: Like `UpdateByCaster(Spell spell, Caster caster) { if (spell is IProjectileSpell p) { p.Speed *= caster.SpeedModifier;}}`

Comment: @Hodge, fields and properties are essentially state of a type. So, base type method definition knows nothing about derived types state. That's why you have to override method. Move some common state to the base type if possible.

Comment: Virtual methods are great, but it seems to me that in this case the `SpeedModifier` actually belongs to the base class, and should be set to `1.0` unless a descendent class sets it differently. That way your logic will continue to work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, there are many ways to accomplish your goals, and there's no clear winner.

You could make `dmg` a property of the base class (`Spell`).

```
class Spell
{
    public float dmg;
}
class Fireball : Spell
{
    // dmg is inherited from `Spell`

    public float projectileSpeed;
}
```

If not all spells deal damage, you could have an intermediate parent class (`DamageDealingSpell`) to have this.

But if there are other similar properties of spells to consider (`AreaEffectSpell`) that might only partially overlap this property, you'll run into issues because you can't inherit from both types. So you could switch to using interfaces instead. Then your modifier function has to do things like this:

```
if (spell is IDamageDealingSpell damageDealingSpell)
{
    damageDealingSpell.dmg *= caster.dmgModifier;
}
if (spell is IProjectile projectile)
// ... etc.
```

I often find inheritance is overused, and there are simpler ways to represent the concepts that lend them to better reuse.

You could just pack all the properties into the Spell type itself, and not worry about child classes, for example. You'd give the Spell class a `Name` property to keep track of which spell it is. Spell types could be defined with data in a text file that you read in, rather than each having their own class in the code. You could make the properties nullable (`float? projectileSpeed`) so they can be left empty if they don't apply to a particular spell type.

Or maybe those different properties are really the same kind of attribute:

```
class NumericAttribute
{
    public string Kind;
    public float Value;
}
class Spell
{
    public string Name;
    public List<NumericAttribute> Attributes;
}
class Caster
{
    public List<NumericAttribute> AttributeModifiers;
}
```

Then the code for modifying the spell doesn't change based on the spell type, or based on what types of modifiers exist:

```
var attributesToModify = 
    from attribute in spell.Attributes
    join modifier in caster.AttributeModifiers on attribute.Kind equals modifier.Kind
    select (attribute, modifier);
foreach(var pair in attributesToModify)
{
    pair.attribute.Value *= pair.modifier.Value;
}
```

This would allow you to come up with new attributes without having to change the code: the only classes that need to be aware of those attributes are the ones that want to apply their effect somehow.

Try to think about what's likely to change as you create your game: are you going to come up with a cool new idea for an effect? Weapons that use mana? Consider how each design option might make it easier or harder to make those changes later on, and then pick one that seems like it gives you the flexibility that's most important to you. As you progress, notice what's hard or repetitive about your process, and refactor your code to make those pain points easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. I see the problem with not having multiple-inheritance, so I like the interface approach. I was thinking if there was some nice way to iterate through the stats, so I'll look into maybe making that work as well.

Comment: "You could just pack all the properties into the Spell type itself," - this could be better for allowing user-created spells like in some Elder Scrolls games.   Types like area vs. single-target, direct vs projectile, element type, ....  and a particular spell is just a list of all the type values and strength modifiers.

Comment: I have a unity-specific problem that arose from using the interface approach you suggested; I have previously manually entered in the base stats of the different spells through the inspector in unity. However as I understand when you define a "field" through an interface, it's technically different, and thus the unity inspector no longer allows you to insert values there. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @Hodge: Use true properties instead of fields? `public float dmg {get; set;}` (With the caveat that I haven't used Unity--I'm just guessing based on my knowledge of C#)